# How to have a file open normally in Resharper instead of in "Keep Open" mode

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and Resharper and whenever I search for (and open a file) by name (using the "Go To File" shortcut of Control-Shift-T) the file opens in a "Keep Open" mode, instead of opening normally.  I've searched and can't find anyway to open the file normally.

What setting can I change to make it open normally?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Simply go to : Tools >> Options >> Environment >> Tabs and Windows

Then uncheck the "Allow new files to be opened in the preview tab" in the Preview Tab section

Found the answer from there actually : [Disable file preview in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952185/disable-file-preview-in-vs2012)

Answer (score 11):

And if you want to keep the Preview Tab, but want that currently previewed file to stay open, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Home</kbd>. The equivalent Visual Studio command is `Window.KeepTabOpen`.