# Keep document open in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I noticed in [Visual Studio 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2013) that when you open a document via 'go to definition/f12' the document is only opened temporarily, as soon as you navigate away from the document it closes again.

Now you have to click on the 'keep open' icon in the tab. How do I 'keep open' all those files automatically like in previous versions of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is an optional feature which gives quick navigation to every file in Visual Studio. If you need to keep a file opened all time, you need to ***double click*** it.

Single click will open the file temporarily until you decide to open another file which opens in the same preview window. This feature can be disabled using:

***TOOLS → Options → Environment → Tabs and Windows → Preview Tab → Single-click***

IMO, this is a handy feature (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534694/visual-studio-2012-2013-single-click-opens-file)) just to avoid cluttering up the working space.

Comment: I personally like the new feature. Most of the time, a file is opened for "intermediate tracing" which leads to another definition. This is especially true when a definition being traced leads to a macro or nested macros. The new feature allow me open what "need to" be open.

Comment: I guess i'm too much used to the old situation. Constantly looking for that opened doc that has been closed again ;)

Comment: When a file is open the temporary Preview Tab you can press Ctrl+Alt+Home to keep the file open in a normal tab. Also, if you open several class files using F12 in the Preview Tab you can then use Ctrl+- to navigate backwards through the class files.

Answer (score 28):

From Stack Overflow question *[How to have a file open normally in Resharper instead of in Keep Open mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12536066)*:

> Simply go to: Tools ? Options ? Environment ? Tabs and Windows
>
> Then uncheck the "Allow new files to be opened in the preview tab" in the Preview Tab section

[image: Uncheck all to be able to do F12]

It will disable all preview features, but at least you will be able to do <kbd>F12</kbd> as you wish.

Answer (score 14):

I was annoyed by this feature as well, until I discovered the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+Home`.

If you press that in a document that was just opened, it will be opened permanently.

You can also click on the small button 'Keep Open' here:

[image]