# How to stop Visual Studio from opening a file on single click?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2012 Solution Explorer, when I single click a filename it opens it. This was different from Visual Studio 2010 (required a double click).

Is there a way to make it open on a double click instead of a single click?

Comment: What do you expect it to do after you click (single) on the file name? Nothing? BTW, you can change this behavior in "Environment"-"Tabs and windows". But you should'n, in my opinion ;-)

Comment: On a single click I expect it to be selected, so I can check its properties

Comment: **See Also** [Disable file preview in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10952185/1366033)

Answer (score 639, accepted):

This is called the Preview Tab feature. To change that behavior, go to:

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows

Then look for the "Preview Tab" section, and uncheck the options therein:

[image: Options Window > Environment option > Tabs and Windows sub-option > Preview Tab section]

Comment: It's also an option on the solution explorer itself, one of the buttons at the top toggles it.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the button David is referring to has a tooltip: "Preview Selected Items"

Comment: As the image above shows, you can alt-click a file to avoid the preview tab if you're just clicking it without wanting to see it for whatever reason.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the  "Preview Selected Items"-button David is referring to is at the far right ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to add that button at the far right Rango is referring to looks like a folder with magnifying glass at the bottom left corner ;-) (in VS 2012, at least)

Comment: I actually used this question to see were to enable this as i like the functionality but was reset on my machine so thanks for the great contribution :)

Answer (score 178):

## Option 1: Using icon in Solution Explorer

You can enable or disable the feature in Solution Explorer using the "Preview Selected Items" button.

[image]

The icon is a `Tab` aligned to the right.

## Option 2: Using the Options window

You can enable or disable the feature by going into `Tools > Options` and then `Environment > Tabs and Windows`.

[image]

Answer (score 27):

The **Single-click opens files in the preview tab** text mentioned in rubber boots' answer is missing in VS 2015. Mysteriously, a search for "single click" still brings up the **Environment > Tabs and Windows** option.

So for VS2015 and VS2017, either click the button in Vinicius's answer, or uncheck the **Preview selected files in Solution Explorer** box shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

In Visual studio 12/13, easiest way is to type "single click" in quick search  and than select Tabs and Windows.

And in Tabs and Windows dialogue ,uncheck "Preview selected files in solutions explorer"

[image]

[image: "]

Comment: That's some beautiful highlighting

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+Home`.

If you press that in a document that was just opened, it will be opened permanently.

Item -> right click -> Open With -> Source Code (Text) Editor -> press Set as Default button

Answer (score 1):

It's no longer there in **VS2019**. You enable/disable it through "preview selected Items" in Solution Explorer.

[image: single click to preview source]
[image: Visual Studio 2019 editor settings]