# Visual Studio 2012 - Disable Single-Click Design View

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This is most likely a really stupid question but I have been unable to find a solution on-line thus far, I'm probably searching for the wrong thing.

I want to disable the fact that within Visual Studio 2012 whenever I left click to select a file within the Solution Explorer it automatically opens my VB.aspx files in Design View. It's annoying because then VS assumes I have made changes to the file and I have to exclude the changes when I check-in other files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534694/visual-studio-2012-2013-single-click-opens-file).

I'm on VS2013 now, but there should be a button at the top of the Solution Builder labelled 'Preview Selected Items' or similar.  Toggle it.

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you! I knew it would be staring me in the face.