# Visual Studio Solution Explorer, selected file changes when I click into Main Coding View

Tags: visual-studio

Problem:
I have a file highlighted in Solution Explorer, which is not currently opened.

if I click into the main code window, the solution explorer changes, and selects the filename that I am now looking at in the main code window

It didn't do this for years (decades?) so this is new, and I would love to figure out the option to turn this off.

TIA

Comment: It's probably this button: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18492029/201303

Comment: What's "the main code window"? Is that another file that's open? Also, when you select a file in Solution Explorer, it opens it in preview. Is that what's happening?

Comment: @Julian That is the solution - thank you