# visual studio 2012 is closing other code files when I open any other source file

Tags: visual-studio-2012

So we just switched to VS 2012 and it's making me insane because it has decided that whenever I double click a file to open it it closes the other open file I am looking it. At first I thought it was just a resharper thing (using Ctrl + T) but that isn't it, even if I open classA.cs then go click on classB.cs it closes classA.cs - I have never seen or heard of this before and tried several different Google queries with no luck.

Anyway know what is going on?

Comment: OK - I just got better but the way VS 2012 handles tabs is making me nuts. I would still like to know what caused this.

Comment: Turning off preview mode solved this issue.See the following,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952185/disable-file-preview-in-vs2012

Comment: if you solved the issue, please answer to your question, instead of posting a comment. This will help future reader to know there is an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off preview mode solved this issue.See the following, stackoverflow.com/questions/10952185/…