# How can I turn off Visual Studio 2013 Preview?

Tags: visual-studio, search, command, visual-studio-2013, ctrl

When I want to search files I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>. The search box pops up and then I start typing. But the built-in preview just grabs whatever I have typed and opens the file. Even though I am still typing.

I am trying to open a file called `report_vaccine`, but I only get as far as `report` when the preview opens the first selected report. This has rendered this form of quick file searching pretty much useless, which is frustrating because we have hundreds of procs, and scrolling through and manually finding the file is a huge pain.

If there is a way to turn off preview, I would be fine with that. This command working properly is waaay more important to me than a preview of the file to be opened.

I don't have resharper. I think the command was like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

Comment: appreciate that

Comment: **See Also** [Disable file preview in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10952185/1366033)

Answer (score 214, accepted):

From the menu go to `Tools -> Options` then navigate to `Environment -> Tabs and Windows` and uncheck the Preview Tab checkboxes.

Comment: In particular, the check box that affects the behavior of the Ctrl+comma search box is "Preview selected files in Navigate To"

Answer (score 42):

I like showing screenshots, helps digest the info just a little faster :)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

This is faster: toggle file preview within the Solution Explorer tool-window:

[image]

Comment: Although the icon is a bit different now, this (and the other answers maybe) also work if you want to stop VS from closing the search list in the first hit when using Ctrl+[comma] to find a file/class

Comment: This didn't change behavior when F12ing to `Go To Definition` for me; they'd still open in a preview tab until I followed [tspauld's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19914461/1028230).